# How to feed looped WorksheetFunction calculation outputs into an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, I hope this is clear!

Following VBA code for MC macro does not work. I´m trying to feed loop computations (the Excel beta.inv statistical formula) into an array, and output the completed array into the worksheet for checking. A derivation of this works fine for outputting straight to the worksheet without using an array, but I instead prefer to feed the data into an array for further calculations (and to minimize back/forth between VBA/worksheet to speed things up).

Code:

```
Sub MC()
   Dim n As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   Dim myArray As Variant
   Dim x as Integer

n = Range("L2").Value   
For j = 1 To n
   myArray(x) = WorksheetFunction.Beta_Inv(Range("l5").Value, Range("l3").Value, Range("l4").Value, 0, 1) 
   x = x + 1
Next j
       
'Print values to Immediate Window
For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray) 
  Debug.Print 
  myArray(x)
Next x

End Sub
```

Where cells are L2 = 100, L5 = RAND() formula, L3 = 0.12, and L4 = 0.17 (by the way I will embed that RAND() formula into VBA and remove it from the worksheet once I get this array working!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `myArray(x)` is a 1 dimensional array but ranges are **always** 2 dimensional (even if it is only one row or one column, because only with the second demension of the array it gets a orientation eiter column or row).

Further the size of an array needs to be defined using `Dim` or `ReDim` otherwise the array has no size:

```
Dim myArray(1 To 10) As Variant 'only fixed numbers possible, no variables
ReDim myArray(a To b) 'variable possible (ReDim can also be used without Dim)
```

It should look like something like the following:

```
Sub MC()
    Dim n As Long
    n = Range("L2").Value
    If n < 1 Then Exit Sub 'prevent errors on next line n must be >=1
    
    'define an array that can be written into a range
    ReDim myArray(1 To n, 1 To 1) As Variant 'one column of data with n rows
    
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To n
        myArray(j, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Beta_Inv(Range("l5").Value, Range("l3").Value, Range("l4").Value, 0, 1)
    Next j
    
    'Print values to Immediate Window
    Dim x As Long
    For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        Debug.Print myArray(x, 1)
    Next x
    
    'can be written to a range like
    Range("A1", "A" & n).Value = myArray 'the range must have the same amount of rows/columns as the array or you lose data
End Sub
```